# JSF: f:ajax listener not called for t:selectOneRadio

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, tomahawk

This is my code:

```
<t:selectOneRadio id="someId" layout="spread" forceId="true" forceIdIndex="false" value="#{someHandler.value}"  required="true">
                <f:selectItems value="#{someOtherHandler.values}" var="item" itemLabel="#{item.name}" />
                <f:ajax listener="#{someHandler.toggle}" render="form:all" />       
</t:selectOneRadio>
```

But the toggle-Listener is never called:

```
public void toggle(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
    // ...
}
```

I have googled and found [this bug report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TOMAHAWK-1551), but I don't understand how I can work around it.

Any ideas?

I have Tomahawk 1.1.10 and JSF 2 (MyFaces).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bug states that the issue was resolved in version 1.1.11-SNAPSHOT.

The easiest way to workaround this would be to upgrade to this latest snapshot build.

Comment: Thanks! I can't find that snapshot somehow: http://people.apache.org/repo/m2-snapshot-repository/org/apache/myfaces/tomahawk/tomahawk-project/ http://people.apache.org/repo/m2-snapshot-repository/org/apache/myfaces/tomahawk/tomahawk20/ http://people.apache.org/repo/m2-snapshot-repository/org/apache/myfaces/tomahawk/tomahawk/ - only 1.1.10. Any idea where to find it?

Comment: It seems like it is the latest development and it is not an actual release yet.  They keep these here I think... https://repository.apache.org/index.html#nexus-search;quick~tomahawk  .  Use at your own caution though as this looks like it is in active development.  It may not be very stable.

Comment: I'll think about introducing that library. I don't know if it's a good idea to replace the stable version with this, though. But I depend on the *spread* attribute. Hm. Tough decision! :) Thanks!